# how to retrieve just the strings from an array in wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I know I'm probably doing this in a round about fashion but I don't understand why it wont work or a better way to just retrieve ONLY THE STRING VALUES in an array so that I can move them to a different table. I thought I could iterate through the array list and output only the strings in the array but it is not working :(

```
//database config and wpdb access code...

<?php

    $cbposttitles = $wpdb->get_col('SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts' ); 

    $countofposttitles = count($cbposttitles);

    echo "count of post tiles . $countofposttitles";  //counts correctly
    ?> 
    <br>
    <?php

    for ($x = 0; $x < $countofposttitles; $x++) {
    $individualpost = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID =
    [$x]');

    echo $individualpost;  // does't work
}
?>
```

Comment: $x is just a count, are you sure its going to be the id? and also no [] and also double quotes unless you want to match literal $x. sooo why not get contents and title in one query in the first place

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fin.  I am trying to count each row and then display each var that relates to the id. So if there is 10 posts, the id should be equal to the count number - I note that I incorrectly put in the select query 'post_content' when I should have said 'post_title'. With Regards to the [] should I write "$x" or should the double quotes be instead of the single quotes?  Really appreciate you taking the time to get back to me and I am sorry I am asking stupid questions...

Answer (score 0):

$countofposttitles contains nothing but the number of posts/titles. This you have no use for in your piece code. You probably try to select some kind of ids from your first query and look for each of these in your second. However, this is very inefficient since you're making a lot of unnecessary database requests.

Which strings and/or values to you actually want and what is the purpose? You're using two queries for the same table, either you want both fields or just one? If you want both fields then just select both in one query:

```
SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply PurpleNinja.  I hoped that when I preform a count, the int of the count would equal the number of the ID and so it would display the post_title when x was equal to the id. And yes you are right, I should have put in the select query 'post_title'. Any further help you can give would be really appreciated.